# Why are the results of integrations of a DiracDelta related integrand and its approximations strikingly different?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, symbolic

Let us consider a double integral, treating it as a functional which corresponds a number to a function,

```
Integrate[ Exp[2 x + 3 y]*DiracDelta[x - UnitStep[x + y]], {x, -3/2, 3/2}, {y, -3/2, 3/2}]
```

> `1/E^(9/2) - 2 E^2 + E^(13/2)`

In fact, Mathematica calculates the iterated integral, so we also consider another iterated integral

```
Integrate[Exp[2 x + 3 y]*DiracDelta[x - UnitStep[x + y]], {y, -3/2,3/2}, {x, -3/2, 3/2}]
```

> `-((2 DiracDelta[0])/E^(9/2))`

As we see, the results are strikingly different. Let us consider  approximations of `DiracDelta[x - UnitStep[x + y]]`
in the weak topology (Exactly saying, the functions which are associated with that approximations. I'd like to recall that
the $\delta$-distribution is not associated with any usual function.) ant the limits when those approximations tend to
`DiracDelta[x - UnitStep[x + y]]` in the weak topology:

```
Integrate[ Exp[2 x + 3 y]*UnitBox[(x - UnitStep[x + y])/eps]/eps, {x, -3/2, 3/2},
{y, -3/2, 3/2}, Assumptions -> eps > 0 && eps < 1]
```

> `(-2 E^(7/2) Sinh[eps/2] + 2 E^(9/2) Sinh[eps/2] - Sinh[eps] +  E^11 Sinh[eps])/(3 E^(9/2) eps)`

```
Limit[%, eps -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
```

> `(-1 - E^(7/2) + E^(9/2) + E^11)/(3 E^(9/2))`

and

```
Integrate[Exp[2 x + 3 y]*UnitBox[(x - UnitStep[x + y])/eps]/eps, {y, -3/2, 3/2},
{x, -3/2, 3/2}, Assumptions -> eps > 0 && eps < 1]
```

> `1/(3 eps) E^(-(9/2) - (3 eps)/2) (-2 E^(7/2 + (3 eps)/2) Sinh[eps/2] +  3 E^(9/2 + (3 eps)/2) Sinh[eps/2] +  E^(7/2 + (5 eps)/2) Sinh[eps/2] +  E^(7/2 + (7 eps)/2) Sinh[eps/2] + E^(3/2) Sinh[eps] +  E^(9/2) Sinh[eps] + E^(13/2) Sinh[eps] - E^(3 eps/2) Sinh[eps] +  E^(11 + (3 eps)/2) Sinh[eps] - E^(3/2 + 3 eps) Sinh[eps] -  E^(7/2 + 3 eps) Sinh[eps] - E^(13/2 + 3 eps) Sinh[eps] -  E^(9/2 + eps/2) Sinh[(3 eps)/2] +  2 E^(3/2 + (3 eps)/2) Sinh[eps] Sinh[(3 eps)/2] +  2 E^(13/2 + (3 eps)/2) Sinh[eps] Sinh[(3 eps)/2])`

```
Limit[%, eps -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
```

> `(-1 - E^(7/2) + E^(9/2) + E^11)/(3 E^(9/2))`.

To be sure, let us also calculate those with  non-symmetric approximations:

```
Integrate[Exp[2 x + 3 y]* UnitBox[(x - UnitStep[x + y] - Sqrt[eps])/eps]/eps, {x, -3/2,3/2}, 
{y, -3/2, 3/2}, Assumptions -> eps > 0 && eps < 1];
Limit[%, eps -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
```

> `(-1 - E^(7/2) + E^(9/2) + E^11)/(3 E^(9/2))`

and

```
eps = 0.005; NIntegrate[Exp[2*x + 3*y]*eps/((x - UnitStep[x + y] - eps)^2 + eps^2)/Pi, 
{y, -3/2, 3/2}, {x, -3/2, 3/2}]
```

> `223.53`

(compare the latter with `N[(-1 - E^(7/2) + E^(9/2) + E^11)/(3 E^(9/2))]` which results in
`221.921` and with `N[1/E^(9/2) - 2 E^2 + E^(13/2)]` which results in `650.375`).

It should be noticed the case under consideration is substantially different from
[that case](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/237252/how-to-explain-these-results-of-integration-of-diracdelta):
two  iterated integrals of  `Exp[2 x + 3 y]*DiracDelta[x - UnitStep[x + y]]` and limits of the integrals of its approximation
in the weak topology `Exp[2 x + 3 y]*UnitBox[(x - UnitStep[x + y])/eps]/eps` as `eps` tends to zero from above produce three
different results; if the limits of the integration are slightly perturbed, then the intersection of the support of  `DiracDelta[x - UnitStep[x + y]]`
with the boundary of the set of the integration does not qualitativily change as

```
ContourPlot[x - UnitStep[x + y] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

shows.

The question is open: what does the result of the integration of `Exp[2 x + 3 y]*DiracDelta[x - UnitStep[x + y]]`
over the square `{x, -3/2, 3/2}, {y, -3/2, 3/2}` mean? The only reference I know where the integration of distributions over
bounded sets is defined is [Antosik, P., Mikusinski, J., Sikorski, R. Theory of distributions. The sequential approach. Reprints. (English) Zbl 0267.46028
Amsterdam: Elsevier Scientific Publishing Company; Warszawa: PWN-Polish Scientific Publishers. XIV, 273 p.(1973)](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0267.46028),
but a smooth integral introduced there does not include the integral under consideration.

Comment: Somebody suggests to close the question as based on options. Which options do the work? Also a downvote is not motivated. What is wrong in my question?

Comment: DiracDelta is a tool of mathematics as applied to physical situations. What real-world object are you attempting to model here?

Comment: @JohnDogy: Thank you for your constant interest to my questions. I don't know such an object. I simply study two syntactically  correct commands of Mathematica which produce doubtful results and ask about it in the forum devoted to Mathematica. Constructive replies of you on the topic are welcome.

Comment: Doubtful results from ill-posed problems are normal. It may be syntactically correct to attempt to pick up a chain saw by its blade, but the outcome will not be pretty.

Comment: @JohnDogy: Can you ground your statement "ill-posed problems "? TIA.

Comment: I already did. What physical object are you investigating? To be well-posed, a problem that employs a tool of mathematical physics should connect to reality.

Comment: @JohnDogy I prefer arguments over emotional words. Recall of [Tikhonov's regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-posed_problem), for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120723/discussion-between-john-doty-and-user64494).

Comment: I don't think Fubini's theorem holds on the original singular integrand. One order gives a wrong result, possibly GIGO or possibly a bug.

Comment: @DanielLchblau: Both `Integrate[ Exp[2 x + 3 y]*UnitBox[(x - UnitStep[x + y])/eps]/eps, {x, -3/2, 3/2},
{y, -3/2, 3/2}, Assumptions -> eps > 0 && eps < 1]` and `Integrate[ Exp[2 x + 3 y]*UnitBox[(x - UnitStep[x + y])/eps]/eps, {y, -3/2, 3/2},
{x, -3/2, 3/2}, Assumptions -> eps > 0 && eps < 1]` tend to `-1 - E^(7/2) + E^(9/2) + E^11)/(3 E^(9/2)) ` as `eps` tends to zero. However, I take into account your (ungrounded) thought .

Comment: You keep on using emotional words like "ungrounded", but your problem has no ground at all. Mere syntax does not count as ground.

Comment: (1) Notes with misspelled names do not give alerts. (2) Again I will point out that this is not a forum for matjhematical proofs. If you need to know why Fubini's theorem does not apply, math.SE would be an appropriate forum to ask about that.

Comment: (3) It's not a mystery though. If you first integrate with respect to y, you have at any given value (of y) but finitely many integrand singular points. This will be fine for the next step. If however you integrate first with respect to x, you have two values for which the integral will not be defined (x=0 and x=1). (4) Obviously any classically integrable approximation to this Delta function will allow Fubini's theorem to apply.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your main question:

```
"Integral[ Exp[2 x + 3 y]*DiracDelta[x - UnitStep[x + y]], {x, -3/2, 3/2}, {y, -3/2, 3/2}]"
==Integrate[Exp[2 0 + 3 y], {y, -3/2, 0}] 
+Integrate[Exp[2 1 + 3 y], {y, -1, 3/2}]
```

This can be seen by examining the argument of `DiracDelta` in your example:

```
ContourPlot[x - UnitStep[x + y] == 0, {x, -3/2, 3/2},{y, -3/2, 3/2}, FrameLabel -> {x, y} ]
```

[image]

It's obvious to first integrate "over x" using the rule `Integrate[DiracDelta[x-p] f[x],{x,p-eps,x+eps}]==f[p]`

The value of the integral follows to

```
Integrate[Exp[2 0 + 3 y], {y, -3/2, 0}]+Integrate[Exp[2 1 + 3 y], {y, -1, 3/2}] 
(*1/3 - 1/(3 E^(9/2)) + (-1 + E^(15/2))/(3 E)==221.921*)
```

It might be "confirmed" numerical with

```
dirac = Function[{x, eps}, Which[-eps < x < eps, 1/(2eps), True, 0]]
NIntegrate[Exp[2 x + 3 y]*dirac[x - UnitStep[x + y], .001], {x,-3/2,3/2}, {y, -3/2, 3/2}]
(*221.921*)
```

final note:
Direct evaluation  with Mathematica

```
Integrate[ Exp[2 x + 3 y]*DiracDelta[x -UnitStep[x + y]], {x, -3/2, 3/2}, {y, -3/2,3/2}]
(*1/E^(9/2) - 2 E^2 + E^(13/2)==650.375*)
```

gives wrong result. Perhaps because argument of DiracDelta also vanishs on the boundary of the integration range...

Comment: Thank you. However, the equality `Integrate[ Exp[2 x + 3 y]*DiracDelta[x - UnitStep[x + y]], {x, -3/2, 3/2}, {y, -3/2, 3/2}]
==Integrate[Exp[2 0 + 3 y], {y, -3/2, 0}] 
+Integrate[Exp[2 1 + 3 y], {y, -1, 3/2}]` is not grounded: `Integrate[ Exp[2 x + 3 y]*DiracDelta[x - UnitStep[x + y]], {x, -3/2, 3/2}, {y, -3/2, 3/2}]` performs a different value.

Comment: If you read my complete answer you might found the "ground"

Comment: No, I don't find arguments there though there's something about it. Thank you anyway.

Comment: It seems surprising that my analytical result gives the same value as your numerical approximations! Let me know  if someone else except you doesn't find arguments in my answer...

Comment: UlrichNeumann(@ does not work.): [Yuriy Golovatyi](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/person.phtml?&personid=21928&option_lang=eng). You may contact him with his kind permission.

Comment: @user64494 Perhaps you and/or  Yuriy Golovatyi present arguments within the stackexchange community. In modern sciences the statement "I don't find arguments there" isn't target oriented. Why didn't you point out suspected errors in my answer?

Comment: UlrichNeumann(@ does not work.): You wrote "It's obvious to first integrate "over x"", but `Integrate[
 Exp[2 x + 3 y]*DiracDelta[x - UnitStep[x + y]], {x, -3/2, 3/2}, 
 Assumptions -> y >= -3/2 && y <= 3/2]` produces `E^(3 y) (-DiracDelta[UnitStep[y]] + (
   2 DiracDelta[3 + 2 UnitStep[-(3/2) + y]] - 
    E^3 DiracDelta[UnitStep[y]])/E^3)`, not the sum of two integrals you work with.

Comment: @user64494 I showed an analytical way to evaluate the integral, because Mathematica fails! It seems to be thin reasoning to use Mathematica again to  disprove my calculation

Comment: UlrichNeumann(@ does not work.): It's unclear tome how you apply "the rule Integrate[DiracDelta[x-p] f[x],x]==f[p]" to a definite integral.

Comment: @user64494 The rule I used is `Integrate[DiracDelta[x-p] f[x],{x,p-eps,x+eps}]==f[p] `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120720/discussion-between-user64494-and-ulrich-neumann).

Comment: UlrichNeumann(@ does not work.): Sorry, you avoid of an answer  how you apply "the rule Integrate[DiracDelta[x-p] f[x],x]==f[p]" to a definite integral as was written in your answer as well as "rule Integrate[DiracDelta[x-p] f[x],{x,p-eps,x+eps}]==f[p]" which is currently written there. I don't know such a rule. Can you give a reference?

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html